# My Prestashop Back Office Is not lising payment methods

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

am a beginner to PrestaShop. my PrestaShop admin side is not listing payment methods. there are two default payment methods. but the backend is not displaying anything. please help.

SCREENSHOT
[image: screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

I found The Solution Just clear the cache and it will work.